# How to submit a list of checkmark values into a form in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a table that displays a list of all logs that have been added. In addition to displaying the info I wanted to have another column of checkboxes that when clicked would allow me to delete them with the corresponding delete button.

The issue that I am having is that I am unable to put the values from my checkboxes into the array of Longs. I also want to keep the functionality of my table as it displays correctly.

For my table I have the following code:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/projects/log/delete/}" th:object="${deleteForm}">
  <div th:each="log : ${allLogs}" class="row">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="active">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{logIds}" th:value="${log.id}" />
        </td>
        <td th:text="${log.teamUsed}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log.opponentStarters}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log.opponentOthers}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log.myStarters}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log.myOthers}"></td>
        <td th:text="${log.result}"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="deleteButton" class="hidden"></button>
</form>
```

The form that I am trying to place the checkbox values into is: (log.id is a long)

```
public class LogDeleteForm {

    private List<Long> logIds = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Long> getLogIds() {
        return logIds;
    }

    public void setLogIds(List<Long> logIds) {
        this.logIds = logIds;
    }
}
```

In my controller I have the following setup for my view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "pokemon_log", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String view(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("addForm", new logForm());
    model.addAttribute("deleteForm", new logDeleteForm());
    model.addAttribute("allLogs", logService.getAllLogs());
    return "log";
}
```

I am able to implement the deletion fine I am just unable to get the Ids that I would like to delete. How can I get the checkbox values placed into the list of longs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my issue was in my deleteLogs method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "delete")
public String deleteLogs(@ModelAttribute("deleteForm") logDeleteForm deleteForm) {
    List<Long> formIds = deleteForm.getLogIds();
    if (formIds == null || formIds.size() == 0) {
        return "redirect:/projects/log";
    }
    for (Long id : formIds) {
        logService.deleteLog(id);
    }
    return "redirect:/projects/log";
}
```

My redirects were both "redirect:/log" instead of "redirect:/projects/log"

Also my button was missing name="delete" because it was unable to qualify as a submit with a delete param.